# YouTube動画からストリーミング中にフレームを取得する方法はありますか。

Tags: html, network, streaming

YouTubeの動画をストリーミング中にプロキシサーバなどでキャプチャし、そこからフレームを取得し画像として扱うことはできますでしょうか。
自分でプロキシサーバを作成し、レスポンスを表示してみましたが、ストリーミングのレスポンスが表示されませんでした。

こちらのページ(http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/Notes/UNIX/lab.youtube.html) で動画をダウンロードできることはわかりましたが、ストリーミング中にリアルタイムでフレームを取得する方法は存在するのでしょうか。

Comment: Chromeで動画を再生する様子をFiddlerで見ると、video/webmやaudio/webmといったContent-TypeのレスポンスがHTTPSで流れてるみたいですね。ストリーミングといってもライブ配信などではないので、再生に先行して大き目のかたまりで受信しているようですが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の方法が適切かどうかは分かりませんが、一例として挙げておきます。

[youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/) と [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) を使います。

```shell
$ lsb_release -ir
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Release:    16.04
$ youtube-dl --version
2015.11.27.1
$ mplayer | head -1
MPlayer 1.2 (Debian), built with gcc-5.3.1 (C) 2000-2015 MPlayer Team

$ youtube-dl 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tn-feaut10' -o - | mplayer -vf screenshot -
```

再生中に `s` キーを押すと、フレームのスナップショットがPNG形式の画像ファイルとして保存されます。

```shell
$ ls
shot0001.png shot0002.png
```

また、`Shift + s` キーを押すと、再度 `Shift + s` キーが押されるまで連続してスナップショットを取ります(toggle)。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
できれば画像出力なしでそのままプログラムに読み込ませたいのですがそのような方法はありませんよね。